# STM32 write signed short into EEPROM

Tags: c, stm32, eeprom

I use STM32F0 mcu with emulated EEPROM. The EEPROM takes data as `EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)` and returns them as `EE_ReadVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t* Data)` but my data are `int16_t`. So my question is, how do I write and read signed short?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the C language is being daft when it comes to things like hardware-related programming, such as EEPROM emulation. Therefore, the *only* reliable solution you can use is this:

```
uint16_t u16;
EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddress, &u16);
int16_t i16;
i16 = (int16_t)u16;
```

or alternatively:

```
memcpy(&i16, &u16, 2);
```

Anything else is unsafe and dangerous. In particular, you *cannot* do this:

```
EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddress, (uint16_t*)&i16); // BAD
```

Nor can you do `i16 = *(int16_t*)&u16; // BAD`.

More information about why, can be found here: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Are you suggesting we don't type cast specifically for hardware modules like EEPROM and others? Or that in general `EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddress, (uint16_t*)&i16); ` is bad? If you check out clean-flight's source code `bt = (*(__IO uint32_t *) (BKPSRAM_BASE + 4)) ;` this is done for SRAM (but not a read/write method). https://github.com/cleanflight/cleanflight/blob/master/src/main/drivers/system_stm32f7xx.c#L200

Comment: @ClamentJohn It is bad in general. But in embedded systems, you must go between different types all the time, as in the case of EEPROM drivers. This was not a problem historically, since embedded compilers relied on non-standard extensions. But with the introduction of gcc in the embedded branch, systems break left and right because they contain strict aliasing violations.

Comment: @ClamentJohn And yes, the "clean-flight" (whatever that is) is broken, in case the memory at those addresses contain anything else than what the compiler recognizes as either uint32_t variables or memory without a previously declared type. Upon further examination it appears to be raw addresses with no declared type, no there's no strict aliasing violation then.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/6e/ed/f1/f7/3e/3f/4c/5c/DM00026574.pdf/files/DM00026574.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00026574.pdf) The data is stored as 16-bit words in memory, so it's `uint16_t`. That's the underlying data type that anything your store in emulated EEPROM must be. Regardless of what you store, it has to have this type.

`int16_t` is guaranteed to have the same size as `uint16_t`. Use an intermediary variable of type uint16_t.

Comment: can you elaborate a little please? Do you mean something like `EE_WriteVariable(VirtAddress, (uint16_t *)myData)` and then `EE_ReadVariable(VirtAddress, (int16_t *)Data)`?

Comment: @muliku Assuming `myData` is defined like this: `int16_t myData`:

The second argument to `EE_WriteVariable` is not a pointer so you need to cast it like this: `(uint16_t)myData`.  The second argument to `EE_ReadVariable` expects an address of an `uint16_t` so you need to cast it like this: `(uint16_t *)&myData`.

Comment: -1 for "cast your pointer" which will invoke undefined behavior and on gcc in particular, break the program. Similarly, the comment by @Fiddling Bits has the same strict aliasing bug. These things are important nowadays, since everyone is using gcc for embedded.

Comment: @Lundin Removed that part